# Fire off a network request in the foreach loop Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, http-get

I have a html table with devices in.  One of my columns in called "Is Online". In order to get this value, we need to do a HTTP get request to the server with the devices Id.

How do I go about doing this in Blazor, and then using the response to update the correct row to 'Yes' or 'No' depending on the HTTP response?

Comment: Do you want it to update periodically too?

Comment: For now no, unles the user refreshes the page, but this could be nice to add as a step 2

Comment: Did you check this documentation? [Call a web API from ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?pivots=webassembly&view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: The issue is not making the http call, its using the result to update the table row.

Comment: There are all standard structure keywords in Razor, like `@for`, `@foreach` and `@if` (and more) in Razor. See [Razor syntax reference for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Sorry I miss the part where your data is updated in loop. I updated my answer to add an example. You can add a flag into your model. Still I recommend looking for batch request (i.e. batch data from one request) instead of bombarding your server with one request per item. But it's up to your business logic.

Comment: @Zapnologica added the answer. Pardon the formatting, the code should work.

Answer (score 2):

Create a component for the device status. In that component call the Async method in `OnInitializedAsync`.

```
<table>
  @foreach(var device in devices)
  {
    <tr @key=device >
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td><DeviceStatus Device=@device /></td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

`DeviceStatus.razor`

```
@IsOnline

@code {
    private bool online = false;
    private string IsOnline => online ? "Yes" : "No";

    [Parameter]
    public Device Device { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        online = await SomeService.GetOnlineStatus(Device);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1++. I'd would do that like that...

Answer (score 2):

Doing API calls in the Renderer loop is a very bad idea.

Why?

1. You have no real control on the Render process and when it runs.
2. You are making the Renderer doing a slow cumbersome task multiple times every render cycle.  The Renderer process isn't designed for data access.

So what should you do?

1. A DI service that gets and manages the data sets required by the UI.  Get all the data access out of the UI.  If you want it "real-time", use a timer loop to refresh the data every x seconds.  On each refresh raise a `DataSetChanged` event if the data set has changed.
2. The component injects the service and wires up to the `DataSetChanged` event.  The event handler calls `StateHasChanged` to refresh the UI if there's something new to display.

Here's a very basic demo.

Service and Data Class.  Register the service as Scoped.

```
using System.Timers;

namespace StackOverflow.Server;

public class RTService: IDisposable
{
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000);

    public readonly List<RTData> Data = new List<RTData>();

    public event EventHandler? DataChanged;

    public RTService()
    {
        {
            Data.Add(new RTData { Name = "Device 1", Live = true });
            Data.Add(new RTData { Name = "Device 2", Live = false });
            Data.Add(new RTData { Name = "Device 3", Live = true });
            Data.Add(new RTData { Name = "Device 4", Live = false });
        }
        _timer.Elapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        _timer.Start();
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
    }

    private async void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // simulated get the data from the network
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Data.ForEach(item => item.NewStatus = !item.Live);
        if (Data.Any(item => item.Live != item.NewStatus))
        {
            Data.ForEach(item => item.Live = item.NewStatus);
            DataChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Elapsed -= OnTimerElapsed;
    }
}

public class RTData
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public bool Live { get; set; }

    public bool NewStatus { get; set; }

}
```

Demo Page:

```
@page "/"
<h3>Real-Time Device Status</h3>
<div class="container">
    @foreach (var device in this.rTService.Data)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                @device.Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <span class="badge @this.ButtonCss(device.Live)">@this.ButtonText(device.Live)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Inject] private RTService rTService { get; set; }

    private string ButtonCss(bool live) => live ? "bg-success" : "bg-danger";
    private string ButtonText(bool live) => live ? "On" : "Off";

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.rTService.DataChanged += this.OnDataChanged;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void OnDataChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
        => this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

    public void Dispose()
        => this.rTService.DataChanged -= this.OnDataChanged;
}
```

Comment: 1++. I agree with you and understand what you mean. Not sure about the OP. The service proposed ( implementing the state and observer patterns) combined with the code by Brian Parker may be a viable solution.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - thanks for the code typo edit.

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem involves data change *after* original data is displayed, this maybe helpful: you can add a flag to your model to indicate data is being loaded:

```cs
    List<TestUser>? Users { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (this.Users == null)
        {
            this.Users = await this.GetUsersAsync();
            // Notify that properties changed
            this.StateHasChanged();
        }

        var onlineTasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var user in this.Users)
        {
            onlineTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                user.IsOnline = await this.GetIsOnlineAsync(user.Id);
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(onlineTasks);

        // Notify that properties changed
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    // Implement your own API call
    static readonly Random random = new Random();
    private async Task<List<TestUser>> GetUsersAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        return new()
            {
                new() { Id = 0, Name = "Foo", },
                new() { Id = 1, Name = "Bar", },
                new() { Id = 2, Name = "XYZ", },
            };
    }

    // Implement your own API call using HttpClient
    private async Task<bool> GetIsOnlineAsync(int id)
    {
        // Simulate a random delay
        await Task.Delay((int)(random.NextDouble() * 3000));

        // Here I just use this as example
        return id % 2 == 0;
    }


    class TestUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool? IsOnline { get; set; } // Null = no data yet
    }
```

Displaying data depends on the data state:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Is Online?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (this.Users != null)
        {
            foreach (var user in this.Users)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@(user.Name)</td>
                    <td>
                        @if (user.IsOnline == null)
                        {
                            <span class="text-muted">Loading...</span>
                        }
                        else if (user.IsOnline.Value)
                        {
                            <span class="text-success">Online!</span>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span class="text-danger">Offline</span>
                        }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

You can use `HttpClient` to make HTTP request just like on server side but obviously it would be translated into HTTP request from browser, so remember that restrictions apply. More documentation here: [Call a web API from ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?pivots=webassembly&view=aspnetcore-6.0)

First, make sure you registered the HttpClient service. In the default template there should already be one, but if there isn't:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => 
    new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
    });
```

In your Blazor `.razor` page:

```
// Inject the HttpClient service
@inject HttpClient Http;

// ...

// Request
List<TestUser>? users;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var resObj = await this.Http.GetFromJsonAsync<TestResponse>("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2");
    this.users = resObj?.Data;
}

class TestResponse
{

    public List<TestUser> Data { get; set; }

}

class TestUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
}
```

It's up to you how to display the result data. See [Razor syntax reference for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0). For example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID > 10?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (this.users != null)
        {
            foreach (var user in this.users)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@(user.First_Name) @(user.Last_Name)</td>
                    <td>@(user.Id > 10 ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Outline of the solution is as follows:

1. Create a service that checks if a particular url is online or offline (make http request => examine the status code => return application specific response)

```
public class StatusChecker
{
   public Task<bool> CheckAsync(string deviceId)
   {
     // check status by pinging server and return the status
   }
}
```

2. Declare this service as scoped or singleton (depending on thread safety, privacy etc etc of your logic)
3. Inject this service in your Blazor page, invoke the CheckAsync for each in your list of deviceIds

```
 @inject StatusChecker Checker
     @if(IsCheckingStatus)    { 
         Checking.....   }\else    {
      <table>     <tbody>
  
    foreach(var device in DeviceIds)   {
      <tr>
        <td @device </td
        <td @statuses[device] </td> </tr>   }      </tbody>      </table>  // if you want to manually refresh again
      <button @onclick="CheckStatuses"Refresh</button>
       }
  
  
     @code {    
       Dictionary<string,string statuses = new ();    
       bool IsCheckingStatus;    
       [Parameter]    
       public List<string DeviceIds {get;set;}
  
     protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()    {
        await CheckStatuses();    }
  
     async Task CheckStatuses()    {
        IsCheckingStatus = true;
        foreach(var devId in DeviceIds)
        {
          var stat = await Checker.CheckAsync(devId);
          statuses[devId] = stat ? "online" : "offline";
        }
        IsCheckingStatus = false;    }
     }
```

P.S. Can someone please format this? SO is simply incapable of formatting Blazor code on Edge.